# Is there any requirement to provide a physical payslip on request in Germany?

Tags: employment, germany

Currently my employer requires employees to log-in to a website to download our monthly pay-slips. I find this frustrating as I receive no notification that a new payslip has been generated, and must recall a website and log-in details to access my payslip that I use at most once a month.

Is there any German law which requires that a physical payslip is to be provided? Or failing that any other similar requirement (e.g. that a payslip may be emailed instead of posted).

Comment: Remembering a URL of a website and a password is a non-issue in times of KeePass etc. Seeing your payslip is your own interest, after all.

Comment: True, but it doesn’t seem an unreasonable request to have this delivered to me. Having it in a web portal seems to benefit the employer with only marginal benefit to the employees.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler That might be true, but there is a legal duty to fulfill - which is not fulfilled by just providing the downloadability.

Answer (score 4):

[Linked is a (German) article on the topic](https://www.d-velop.de/blog/compliance/recht-auf-gehaltsabrechnung-in-papierform/), which introduces you to some intricacies in the German language.

The pay slip must be "erteilt in Textform", given to you as a text. A pdf or other electronic document is a text, and it does say nowhere that the the text needs to be on paper, so on the face of it there is no right to a physical pay slip.

However the verb is "erteilt", "issue the document to you". Just providing a download does not constitute "erteilen". Your employer must not just make sure that you can download the pay slip, he must also make sure that you are aware that there is a facility to download the pay slip and that you can create a physical copy (i.e. when in doubt your employer needs to provide access to a computer and a printer). Also you need to agree with receiving the pay slip in electronic form. By now this usually happens as a clause in your contract, or via a "Betriebsvereinbarung", a company wide agreement between employer and employees.

So if you did not agree to anything like that either in your contract or by accepting an agreement, you could probably insist on a physical pay slip.

<strike>Practically this should not be the hill you want to die on. Forcing an employer who wants to streamline payroll to cut down trees specifically to accomodate you is straining your mutual relationship for a somewhat trivial reason. But then that's just me, YMMV.</strike>

Following Trish's comment and a bit more research, "erteilen" actually means it needs to be provided to you, the burden of accessing it cannot fall on you. So you have the legal right to insist on an e-mail, and contrary to what I wrote previously I would never suggest that you forfeit a legal right. You should still check your contract and all amendments that you have not agreed to download only in the fine print somewhere.

A relevant court case is here: http://www.justiz.nrw.de/nrwe/arbgs/hamm/lag_hamm/j2021/2_Sa_179_21_Urteil_20210923.html

> Die bloße Zurverfügungstellung der Lohnabrechnung in elektronischer
> Form zum Abruf durch den Arbeitnehmer ist keine Erfüllung der Pflicht
> zur Erteilung einer Lohnabrechnung im Sinne des § 362 Abs. 1 BGB.

Which is literally what Trish stated in her comment - providing a download does not amount to supplying you with your pay slip, since this would be asking you to do the job of your employer.

Note that German jurisprudence is not based on precedence, so another court might come to a different conclusion (not likely, but possible).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. My ideal circumstance would be to be emailed the payslip every month, so I was hoping there was a requirement of a physical document as I can imagine it would be an easier argument to have with any employer to say ‘you are failing in your legal duty, but I will accept the compromise of having it emailed to me’ than ‘please change your systems to accommodate me for no reason’

Comment: @NeilTarrant I agree that emailing this should be a trivial thing, but it does not seem to be part of any payroll software I am familiar with used in Germany. Since encrypted e-mail is still rare, this might be a security/privacy thing - after all, the pay slip contains all sorts of confidential information.

Comment: downloadable on a server owned by the company is not properly "erteilt"  - the document must be e-mailed at least. As for payroll software: DHL e-mails the Gehaltsabrechnung to participating employees since about half a decade to decade.

Comment: @Trish well, I am not familar with the DHL software :-) But your point is taken - the pay slip needs to be provided to the employees, the burden of accessing it cannot fall on them (unless they have agreed to it). So my answer is not completely wrong, but wrong about the relevant point. I guess I better fix that, then.